# How to keep zsh running after command execution?

Tags: zsh

I've been using this [bash stanza](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123192) to start a new shell with my python virtual environment.

```
bash -i <<< 'source venv/bin/activate; exec < /dev/tty'
```

Naively, I translated it to zsh:

```
zsh -i <<< 'source venv/bin/activate; exec < /dev/tty'
```

It seems that my activate script is not run when this zsh stanza is invoked. How do I achieve the same functionality?

Comment: `zsh -i <<< 'echo foo'` also doesn't echo. It has something to do with the `-i` option.

Comment: My guess: Since `-i` makes zsh an interactive shell, it tries to read its commands from the attached tty or pty, instead from stdin. Telling it to take the input from somewhere else, does not work. For the same reason, `zsh -i scriptname` does not work (at least on my platform, which is Cygwin). This contradicts the man-page which explicitly says with `-i`:  _It is still possible to specify a script to execute_. Perhaps a bug in zsh?

Comment: From a comment on #zsh on freenode, I gather that <<< zle uses fd10, not stdin. The most direct translation might then be `zsh -i --nozle <<< 'source venv/bin/activate; exec < /dev/tty; setopt zle'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info came from a conversation on #zsh on freenode. (That channel does not seem to be logged). The complication seems to be that the zsh line editor, zle, uses `/dev/fd/10` rather than stdin. This is regarded as an implementation detail not documented in the zsh manuals.

The most direct translation to zsh might be

```
zsh -i --nozle <<< 'source venv/bin/activate; exec < /dev/tty; setopt zle'
```

Another way to activate a virtual environment might be

```
zsh -c 'source venv/bin/activate && exec zsh -i'
```

Another factor to consider is the activate script written by `python -m venv` emphasizes that `venv/bin/activate` should be run from bash (`venv/bin/activate.zsh` is notably absent), so maybe the safest thing to do is

```
bash -c 'source venv/bin/activate && exec zsh -i'
```

Answer (score 2):

Though, as I expressed in my comment, the behaviour you see could be a bug in zsh (at least it seems to me that it contradicts the information in the man page), I can suggest the following workaround:

Every interactive shell you open, sources your `~/.zshrc`, and you want to have sometimes an interactive zsh, which in addition sources your Python environment settings. Hence I would add in your .zshrc the following lines:

```
[[ ${set_py:-no} == yes ]] && source ~/venv/bin/activate
unset set_py
function pyzsh
{
  set_py=yes zsh "$@"
}
```

From your interactive shell, you can then do a `pyzsh` to create a an interactive zsh with Python settings, and a mere `zsh` to create an interactive zsh without. The `-i` is unnecessary, since a shell started in this way as a child of your interactive shell, will also be interactive.